# Flutter app data was cleared after rebuild or update from testflight?

Tags: ios, flutter

**Platform**: iOS

**Scenario**:

Allow user to pick an image as cover in the App. But only save data locally, which means that I need to store image in my App data directory, instead of uploading it to cloud service.

**Flutter doctor -v**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 14.0 23A5286i darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-HK)
    • Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel stable at /Users/jonathan/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision efbf63d9c6 (2 days ago), 2023-08-15 21:05:06 -0500
    • Engine revision 1ac611c64e
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

⣻
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jonathan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A5209g
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone (mobile) • 00008101-001234560BB1001E • ios            • iOS 16.6 20G75

    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Jonathan’s iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Code:

```
XFile? pickedFile =
await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery,);

// save the image <File> in a variable
if (pickedFile == null) { return; }

File _storeImage = File(pickedFile.path);
final fileName = basename(pickedFile.path);
final ext = extension(pickedFile.path);

final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filepath = '${appDir.path}/sometext_${e.name}${ext}';

// copy the image to a new <File> in app data dir
final File localImage = await _storeImage.copy(filepath);
```

And I use `filepath` to display Image. With that code, it works when I pick image first. But if I rebuild code or build a new version to testflight, and update it from testflight, the image lost and comes out the following error

```
flutter: [2023/08/18 14:29:33] [LEVEL.ERROR] read from file "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B50AB25-B89F-47DD-A44B-93AA7203BEDE/Documents/sometext_avatar.jpg" error: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B50AB25-B89F-47DD-A44B-93AA7203BEDE/Documents/sometext_avatar.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

**Questions**

1. If I want to save image from user library in app data directory, and reserve it no matters rebuilding, updating version. How to do that?
2. Any better solutions?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can try using local database like fqlite, sqflite_sqlcipher to store your path.